# Remediating Veracode CWE ID 117 (Improper Output Neutralization for Logs) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, veracode, secure-coding

I have the following code which, if I'm reading other topics on this subject correctly, should not cause a Veracode scan to flag CWE 117 but it is. There are some other 'answers' for Java/C# but I've not found anything for VB.NET.

My code is like this:

```
    Public Function WriteToEventLog(ByVal Entry As String, Optional ByVal AppName As String = "adCoreLibrary", Optional ByVal EventType As EventLogEntryType = Nothing, Optional ByVal LogName As String = "Application", Optional ByVal EventID As Integer = 0, Optional ByVal TaskCategory As TaskCategory = 0) As Boolean

    Dim objEventLog As New EventLog()

    Try
        ' We will try and create our own event log but if not, use the optional default 
        If Not EventLog.SourceExists(AppName) Then
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(AppName, LogName)
        End If

        ' Initialise event log
        objEventLog.BeginInit()

        ' Set the source
        objEventLog.Source = AppName

        ' Write entry
        If Entry IsNot Nothing Then
            ' THE FOLLOWING LINE IS BEING FLAGGED AS CWE-117 NON-COMPLIANT
            objEventLog.WriteEntry(Entry.Replace(vbLf, "_"c).Replace(vbCr, "_"c).Replace(vbTab, "_"c), EventType, EventID, CShort(TaskCategory))
        End If


        ' End initialisation
        objEventLog.EndInit()

        Return True
        Exit Function

    Catch ex As Exception
        If CType(My.Settings.adLogMode, LogMode) <> adCoreLogging.LogMode.Empty Then
            My.Application.Log.WriteEntry("An error occured when trying to write to the Windows Event Log: " & ex.Message.ToString)
            Return False
        End If
    Finally
    End Try

    ' If we get here, we've had a problem
    Return False

End Function
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here please?

Comment: Have you tried applying one of the Java/C# answers?

Comment: Those answers led me to adding Replace(vbLf, "_"c).Replace(vbCr, "_"c).Replace(vbTab, "_"c) but that doesn't appear to have remediated. Additionally, I'm not great at reading Java/C#

Answer (score 0):

Well, for anyone who stumbles across this....I worked out the answer.

I had to substitute the offending line for the following (after importing System.Web):

```
Dim newEntry As String = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Entry)
objEventLog.WriteEntry(newEntry, EventType, EventID, CShort(TaskCategory))
```

I've no idea why Veracode allowed that since it's still the same thing in essence but, there we are.